# Find the locus of the centroid of a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, geometric-construction

Given triangle $ABC$, with points $B(2,3)$ and $C(-2,6)$ and the fact the perimeter is 14, how can we find the locus of its centroid? I do not even know how to begin.

Comment: Let $M$ be the mid point of $B$ and $C$. Find the locus of $A$ first. It is an ellipse with $B$, $C$ as foci and $M$ as center. The centroid $X$ of triangle $ABC$ is lying on the median $AM$ with $|AM| : |XM| = 3:1$.

Comment: @achillehui: That is excellent. Why don't you add it as an official answer?